# My angular material date range picker is not working and doesn't provide an icon to select

Tags: angular-material, ionic4, angular-daterangepicker

I've copied the identical code from StackBlitz and the material date range picker isn't working in my app.

here is the exact code I'm using:

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
  <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker">
    <input matStartDate placeholder="Start date">
    <input matEndDate placeholder="End date">
  </mat-date-range-input>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
</mat-form-field>
```

And this is what it looks like...it's only an input field but there's no data range picker to select from

[image]

```js
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 9.1.12
Node: 10.16.0
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 9.1.12
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.12
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.12
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.12
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.12
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.12
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.12
@angular/cdk                      9.2.4
@angular/fire                     5.4.2
@angular/material                 9.2.4
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.12
@schematics/angular               9.1.12
@schematics/update                0.901.12
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.8.3
webpack                           4.42.0
```

I'd like to be able to select the range picker and let the user select the data range.

Comment: Perhaps you're missing the theme stylesheet? See https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-4-include-a-theme for reference.

Comment: Mine didn't work too, I updated to angular 11 last week and now it's fixed.